# How to disallow adding a specific plugin to a PlaceholderField in a custom Django (CMS) application

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-cms

I made a custom Django app for adding simple blog posts functionality with different sections that can be hooked to any page showing a selected section. It was made as an Apphook to a Django CMS page.

It works by adding the post's title and metadata (date etc.) and upon save there is an Edit button to live edit the post on a page. I am using the PlaceholderField model field which adds a placeholder that accepts all the available plugins.

Since I also made a CMS Plugin that can show Latest posts from any available section I would like to prevent users to add the CMS plugin to my post's detail page placeholder since it raises the RecursionError.

The thing is, a CMS plugin should not be added to the application's PlaceholderField.

I managed to resolve the problem (for now) by adding the CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF to my settings.py file with the restriction for my Latest Posts plugin but since it is a GitHub public repo I would like to disallow it in my app's config by default if possible. It currently works as follows.

```py
CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
    'post_detail': { # name of my model's PlaceholderField
        'name': _("Post content"), # override default name with more verbose one
        'excluded_plugins': ['LatestPostsPlugin'], # exclude from adding to 'post_detail'
    },
}
```

If it helps you can look into the code at my [GitHub account](https://github.com/aacimov/django-posts/), any suggestion is appreciated.